# firebase putfile in kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

`putFile()` method showing unresolved reference in kotlin

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode==Gallery_Intent && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
            val uri = data!!.data
            val imgstr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images")
            uri.putFile(imgstr)
    }
```

`uri.putFile(imgstr)` showing error what to do??

Answer (score 1):

[putfile()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#putFile(android.net.Uri)) is a method of `StorageReference`.  The code should be:

```
imgstr.putFile(uri)
```